# What time period is recommended between having children?

Tags: baby

I have a baby, and he is 2 months old.   I want some time (about 3 years) before my next child. My question is: what is the safest and an acceptable time period between having children in Islam?

Comment: I don't think that there's any rule or recommendation for this Issue in Islam, we are encouraged to have children, we are asked not to avoid having children when married because of reasons like fear not being able to feed them. Scholars however allow some kind of "family planning"...